# Figure in Revtex4

Tags: floats, two-column, revtex

I'm using MiKTeX2.9 for writing paper:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,aps,showpacs,prl,superscriptaddress]{revtex4}
....
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

and I'm trying to place an eps figure left, so that the matching second column contains text.
If I use:

```
\begin{widetext}
.....
\end{widetext}
```

I get blank matching right hand side.
When using:

```
\begin{figure*}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\epsfig{file=figure1.eps,width=0.4\textwidth}
\caption{mycaption}
\label{fig1}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

I get figure flush left, but centered label, and no text in matching second column.
Also, having problem with floating,i.e. placing figure on the right spot. Help, please.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick hint: If you indent lines of LaTeX code by four spaces, they will automatically be pretty-printed by the site's software. Indenting the lines is accomplished easily by highlighting them and clicking on the `{}` "button" in the row above the editing window.

Comment: Incidentally, you have stated what you're getting right now, but it's not entirely clear what you actually want (and how that deviates from the current state). Please provide more information.

Comment: @Mico I explaind what I want to achieve: I'm trying to place an eps figure left (i.e. in the first column), so that the matching second column contains text. Example: http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0601119.pdf

Comment: @Boki Don't load `epsfig` and don't use its syntax: it's old and unsuppported. With `graphicx` you do `\includegraphics[width=9.4\textwidth]{figure1.eps}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you're just trying to get a figure into a single column in the text. There's a few issues with your code: The `\widetext` environment is only intended for placing full width equations into the middle of two column text. Using `figure*` creates full width figures in two column documents which can only be placed at the top or bottom of a page or on a float page, which is probably what's causing your figure placement issues. Enclosing the figure in a `minipage` with `width=\textwidth` creates a minipage the width of both columns that text outside of the minipage cannot enter.

If your intent is to simply have a figure in a single column embedded in the text, all you need to do is use the normal `figure` environment (no star), no `minipage`, and no `flushleft`:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{image}
    \caption{mycaption}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

Note, the `\textwidth` in the `width` option of your figure command means something different now that it's out of the minipage. The minipage was a single column and `\textwidth` referred to the width of the entire minipage, but in this case, `\textwidth` is the width of both columns. You can use `\columnwidth` to refer to the width of a single column, if it's easier.

If you meant that you want a separate block of text that follows the figure in the right column, all you need to do is create two minipages inside the figure environment:

```
\begin{figure*}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image}
        \caption{mycaption}
        \label{fig1}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
        Text here goes in the next column.
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

Note the use of `figure*` to get the full text width for the environment and that each minipage is `\columnwidth` wide. The `[b]` argument for the minipage aligns the text contents to the bottom of each minipage and `\hfill` fills up the space in between the two minipages so they line up with the columns.

Comment: I notice now that the first case seems to be what you want, from looking at the paper you linked, so you can ignore the second part, though it might be helpful to others. The way you worded your question was ambiguous without the example.